# how to clear/reset invalid input in integer input fields in angular dart?

Tags: angular, dart, material-design, angular-dart

I am new to angular dart. I started developing a web app recently which allows the user to edit and list user details. I was using "ngForm" to create forms and material input to get inputs from the user. I use "ngModel" to bind data.
i have a "clear" button in the form which clears all the form fields by calling form.reset(). However, this is not clearing the field that has invalid input in it. I have an input field (age) of type "number". When the user types string in it and hits clear button, the input is not getting cleared.
Here is the code:

```
<div>
  <div *ngIf="user != null">
    <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
    <div>
      <form #editUserForm="ngForm">
        <material-input [(ngModel)]="user.name"
                        ngControl="userName"
                        #userNameInput="ngForm"
                        label="user name" type="text"
                        error="{{getError('name')}}"
                        required>
        </material-input>
        <material-input [(ngModel)]="user.age"
                        ngControl="age"
                        #ageInput="ngForm"
                        label="age"
                        type="number"
                        error="{{getError('age')}}"
                        required>
        </material-input>
        <material-input [(ngModel)]="user.emailId"
                        ngControl="emailId"
                        #emailIdInput="ngForm"
                        label="email id"
                        type="text"
                        error="{{getError('email_id')}}"
                        required>
        </material-input>
        <div>
          <material-button (click)="clearFieldErrors()"
                           (trigger)="save()"
                           raised>
            Save
          </material-button>
          <material-button (click)="editUserForm.reset()">
            Clear
          </material-button>
          <material-button (click)="goBack()"
                           raised>
            Back
          </material-button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I found the error was due to the fact that string input in integer input field (age) is taken as "null" and so when calling editUserForm.reset() nothing happens.  Can anyone please help me?

Comment: in clear button, call the function and try to create a new instance for the user object

Comment: I am getting the user object from the server. Re Fetching an user is too costly @Yuvaranjani

Comment: Thanks there is a bug in material_number_accessor here: https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/3442ade7beb3fbc52e6169d19405a32fdeb5c5ea/angular_components/lib/material_input/material_number_accessor.dart#L112 I should have a fix with the next release